# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0%' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a problem with SQL Server.

I've created a table like this:

```
create table Components 
(
    pk BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    id VARCHAR(50),
    descr VARCHAR(50),
    in_m INT,
    in_iy INT,
    p_fw VARCHAR(5000)
);
```

and I'm trying to insert a couple of values:

```
insert into Components (id, descr, in_m, in_iy, p_fw) 
values ('FW000_A', '0%', 0, 0, '[0.0,0.0,0.0]'),
       ('FW000_B', '1%', 1, 1, '[1.0,1.0,1.0]');
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 111
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0%' to data type int.

even though the column `descr` is correctly defined as `varchar(50)`.

Can anybody help me please? Why is SQL Server trying to convert my strings to int values?

Comment: Your code works for me in SQL Server 2014. http://rextester.com/UOOT87695 Are you sure it's the same table you just created? Same schema, etc.?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Express 2012 but yes, I have the "use mydb;" statement at the beginning of the file. EDIT: I tried to add the notation [schema].[table] for both the create and insert queries, but I'm obtaining the same result as before...

Comment: If you run a SQL Trace (or use https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) what is the actual SQL being passed across the wire?

Comment: A database is not the same as a schema. Check again? Like mydb.dbo.components vs mydb.AnotherSchema.components

Comment: Does running that INSERT work if you try it outside of the app (e.g. in SQL Management Studio)?

Comment: The code works fine here as well: http://rextester.com/live/EAL20795

Comment: I'm actually running my queries from SQL Management Studio. I also tried to create the table in a different schema, like *create table newdb.xyz.Components(... * but running *insert into newdb.xyz.Components(...* nothing changes... I'm trying with a SQL Trace right now and I'll let you know (thanks you all for the answers!!!)

Comment: Any triggers on that table?

Comment: no trigger, I just created it from scratch

Comment: Can you provide actual values which are failing? I cannot see how this can fail with the data in the example. Perhaps you have one record to be inserted which is out of order (i.e. the percentage is in the third place, instead of second)?

Comment: the values I wrote above are copied and pasted from my sql script file. The strange point is that the failing line is *insert into Components(...*. Moreover if I insert each line separately it works fine...

Comment: What do you mean by `Moreover if I insert each line separately it works fine... `? Can you show us the exact code that you are executing that does work? And the exact code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's missing from your question is that you have more than just the two `values` lines you've shown, and one of the other ones has an integer literal for the `descr` column, rather than a string.

This example produces the same error:

```
declare @t table (Descr varchar(50) not null)
insert into @t(Descr) values
('0%'),
(12)
```

What I believe happens is that SQL Server first tries to determine the data types for all columns in the `values` clause. Using data type precedence rules, it observes a `varchar` literal in one row and an `int` literal in the other, and so determines that the overall type for this column is `int` and attempts to perform the conversion that leads to the error.

During this process, it does *not* use any information about the target table into which the `values` are going to be placed, including the data types of the columns there.

Comment: You're absolutely right!!! There was a value `100` without quotes in the 2nd column, at about the 436th inserted tuple. Probably a bug in my sql auto-code generator. BUT, MORE IMPORTANT, I LEARNT THIS IMPORTANT CONCEPT `During this process, it does not use any information about the target table into which the values are going to be placed, including the data types of the columns there.`    Thanks to everybody for your support, issue solved!

Answer (score 1):

run this and verify the data types;

```
  sp_columns Components
```

Looks like 'descr' is really an integer